# Bamboo Java specs, single pipeline repository and multiple projects

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I'm really interested in adopting Bamboo's Configuration as Code model, but I'm currently struggling a bit to find best practices/documentations/tutorials to implement the below scenario:

I have 50+ (Java) projects, each one living in a separate repository on Bitbucket. Thus, 50+ repository. I would like to have a common shared Pipeline for all of them.

How to achieve this?

I managed to create a project specific pipeline (held in bamboo-specs folder), but I cannot afford having 50+ different pipeline definition, as tasks defined in this pipeline might change over time...

What I would like to have ideally is a project independent repo containing only the pipeline definition... and somehow instruct Bamboo to fire the defined stage/jobs/tasks every time a new push is made on any branch of the above mentioned 50+ repos.

Is this somehow feasible (without hardcoding repo references in pipeline project) ?

My company CI runs on Bamboo 6.8.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently have the same problem in our company. We contacted atlassian and It recommended us to have **one Java Project** and manage all our projects from there.
This way, each time we need to update our pipeline we need to just run the Java Project one time.

At the moment we have a JSON configuration file:

```
{
"project": [
    {
        "key": "PROJECTKEY",
        "name": "Project name",
        "description": "testing",
        "plans": [
            {
                "key": "PUNO",
                "name": "plan 1",
                "description": "plan description",
                "repositoryName": "repository link / linked repository name",
                "branches": [ "master", "develop"],
                "templateBuild": "TemplateName",
                "templateDeploy": "TemplateName",
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "key": "",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Java then read this file and generate/update our plans.

If you need bamboo to run the pipeline every time a new push is made you can define triggers in the Java Pipeline Definition.

Here is also an example of my @bambooSpecs main method:

```
ConfigurationFile file = new ConfigurationFile("configurationFile.json");
Project[] proyectos = file.getProjects();
if (proyectos != null && proyectos.length >= 1) {
    List<com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.Plan> bambooPlans = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Project p : proyectos) {
        for (Plan plan : p.getPlans()) {
            Class<?> buildClass = Class.forName("com.my.company.templates.build." + plan.getTemplateBuild());
            TemplateBaseBuild template = (TemplateBaseBuild) buildClass.getDeclaredConstructor(TemplateBaseBuild.getConstructorClassArgs()).newInstance(p.getKey(), p.getName(), p.getDescription(), plan.getKey(), plan.getName(), plan.getDescription(), "", plan.getRepositoryName(), Utils.VariablesToBambooVariable(plan.getVariables()));
            for (com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.Plan currentPlan : template.getPlans()) {
                bambooPlans.add(currentPlan);
            }
            //TODO: deploy
        }
    }
    bambooPlans.forEach(bambooServer::publish);

}
```

We needed to define templates since our projects can use different technologies. Each template has the Pipeline definition (Stages, Tasks, Permissions, Triggers,etc.)

I know there's probably a better way to achieve this, but that's the solution we found at the moment.

Here is the official documentation: https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/6.8.1/specs-java.html

Triggers: https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/6.8.1/specs-java.html#build-triggers

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was actually surprised by the lack of official how-tos...As you said this is kind of a workaround, but might help for the time being. Hope atlassian will add this feature in future releases!

Comment: Interestingly enough, `plan.getTemplateBuild()` does not exist in the 6.10.4 api version.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will answer your question, on my side I am putting everything in the same repository, and sharing piece of Java code to a common library. The method I use is described [here](https://yayimorphology.org/bamboo-specs-project-sharing.html):

- one common library
- single project using the common: note that a single project may contain several `@BambooSpec` annotated class and hence several plans or deployments. I organize those in such a way that those builds are coupled in the set of build projects I have
- manual push from command line